# Firebase Crash Reporting, The first argument does not look like a service account file

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, terminal, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) for Crash Reporting, and I can't find full information about crashes like class name, or method name.

The only option I have on the console is:

> Upload symbol file to symbolicate future stack traces for UUID
>   XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

When I try to apply the command below in the `terminal` as per [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) advice:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

I'm getting the following warning and nothing changed on the console:

> ./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload:83: warning: The first argument does
>   not look like a service account file.

Any ideas how to solve this warning or make the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) crash report readable?

Comment: Did you follow everything on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios)?

Comment: Yes, line by line

Comment: So why are you using `batch-upload`?  I see nothing about that on the linked page.

Comment: if you have all the files in place and you require bitcode, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613105/3331991) answer. It is a script that will automate the process just running from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of parameters that needs to be passed with batch-upload. Consider checking the parameters using the command:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -h
```

Here is a sample of how this script can be used:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -p <Path for GoogleService-Info.plist> -i <Path of Info.plist> <Service account JSON file> <UUID>
```

I would recommend not using "~" for home directory. Instead consider using the absolute path.

That said - whatever is mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios works for me.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload ./Pods/ServiceAccount.json xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

you need to put the full path of the json file, not only it's name.