# IOS upload symbol files for crash reporting fail

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

[image: xcode error img]

> /Users/appledev018/LarsonApp/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:335: error: curl exited with non-zero status 35.
>
> #### hello
>
> Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

I follow the guide to set up firebase crash reporting and when I run my project get above error

and following is my script

```
echo "### hello world"
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:688585241582:ios:0203552cad37c112
echo "### hello google"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PROJECT_DIR}/ServiceAccount.json"
echo "### hello"
```

[image: my script]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Check your internet connection in your system.

Answer (score 2):

Enable "Run Script only when install" in build phases. Then it'll run as expected. This will avoid to upload the script each time when run the system.

Please refer attached screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have bitcode enabled, you can use this script to automate the process and not worry about the rest.

**Follow these steps carefully**

1. Add your unzipped dsym folder to your project's main directory
2. Add this script to the dsym folder
3. Open terminal
4. cd into the dsym folder in the project's main directory
5. Run this python script i.e 'python batch_upload_files.py'

https://github.com/hanijazzar/Contributions/blob/master/batch_upload_files.py

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am a bit late, but here is a solution.

The problem is that `curl` can not verify the SSL certificate on the remote server and therefore blocks the transfer because it seems to be insecure.

You have 2 options:

1) Add `-k` as an option to the `curl` call. (This means to edit the script in the pod.)

2) Allow insecure SSL connections generally. (This disables certificate chain checking but leaves other validation enabled.)
`$ echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc`

Comment: It's not about curl, it's about firebase-crash-reporting run phase script which developers can't  touch it.